# If $X\ge0$, $e^{sX} $ is integrable for every $s\le a$ and $X^k$ is integrable for every $k$, then $e^{sX}X^k$ is integrable for every $s<a$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, expectation, moment-generating-functions

I encounter the following problem in homework:

$X$ is nonnegative random variable. Show if $\mathbb{E}[e^{sX}] < \infty$ for $s\in(-\infty, a]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X^k] < \infty$ for all $k$, then $\mathbb{E}[e^{sX}X^k] < \infty$ for $s<a$. I tried using cauchy schwarz inequality and bounding $e^{sX}X^k$ by some other functions that have finite expectations, but they doesn't seem working. Also don't use differentiation inside the integral since this is actually part of the problem in proving differentiation under the integration.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: What restrictions are put on $s$ in $E[\exp^{sX}X^k]$?  Is it allowed to equal $a$?

Comment: $s\in(-\infty,a]$ I believe. @kimchilover

Comment: Oh, I think it is actually $s\in (-\infty, a)$. Sorry @kimchilover

Comment: If $s\in (-\infty,a)$ you can use Holder's inequality

Comment: But none of them is bounded when $x\in [0, \infty)$. How to use Holder's inequality though? @clark

Comment: Hoelder inequality does not require that integrands are bounded.

Comment: using $p = 1$, and $q = \infty$?@SangchulLee

Comment: For $p=1+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is small enough so that $s(1+\epsilon)\in (-\infty, a)$

Comment: You can choose $p = 1+\epsilon$ with $ps < a$ for $e^{sX}$ and $q = \frac{p}{p-1}$ for $X^k$: $$\mathbb{E}[ e^{sX}X^k ] \leq \mathbb{E}[e^{psX}]^{1/p} \mathbb{E}[X^{qk}]^{1/q} < \infty. $$  But it turns out that neither of the assumptions $X \geq 0$ nor $\mathbb{E}[X^k] < \infty$ is essential for proving your claim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that $X$ is a $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variable such that $\mathbb{E}[e^{sX}] < \infty$ for all $s \in (-\infty, a)$. Then it follows that $\mathbb{E} \left| X^k e^{sX} \right| < \infty$ for all $k \geq 0$ and $s \in (-\infty, a)$.

This follows from $|x|^k \leq M(e^{\epsilon x} + e^{-\epsilon x})$, where $M = M(k,\epsilon) > 0$ is a constant depending only on $k$ and $\epsilon$. So if $s < a$ and we pick $\epsilon > 0$ so that $s + \epsilon < a$,

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[ |X|^k e^{sX}]
\leq M \left( \mathbb{E}[ e^{(s+\epsilon)X}] + \mathbb{E}[ e^{(s-\epsilon)X}] \right)
< \infty.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ have density function proportional to $f(x)=\exp(-x)/(1+x^2)$ for $x\ge0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x<0.$  Then obviously $E|X|^k<\infty$ for all $k>0$, and $E\exp(sX)<\infty$ for all $s\le 1$.  But equally clearly, $E\exp (X) X^k = \infty$ for all $k\ge 1$.

Comment: Oh, I think it is actually $s\in (-\infty, a)$. Sorry

Comment: But how would it change if $s$ is strictly less than $a$?

Comment: Edit your question to reflect the new version of the question.